# Sending Client Certificate with cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I'm trying to send a cURL request to a URL which requires authentication. However I'm having trouble sending the client certificate with it.

Error returned is

```
unable to set private key file: 'privkeyfile.pem' type PEM
```

And the script looks like this:

```
$url = "correcturltosendrequest.com";
$post_string = "string of SOAP tags";

$keyFile = realpath("privkeyfile.pem");
$caFile = realpath("cafile.pem");
$certFile = realpath("pubkeyfile.pem");
$certPass = "pasword";

$soap_do = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $caFile);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certPass);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $post_string); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string) )); 

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
$err = curl_error($soap_do);
```

My googling tells me that this is either the script not having access to the file in question (realpath returns the full correct path. Have set everyone all access to the folder. Running in EasyPHP right now if it makes a difference)...

Or I'm just doing something wrong with these certificate files. Unfortunately my knowledge of pem files is limited at best.

I have the following PEM files at my disposal:

- a public key
- a private key
- a root CA
- an intermediate CA

Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you get if you run `var_dump(file_exists($keyFile));`

Comment: bool(true). Also just echoing $keyFile returns the correct full path to the file.

Comment: And the file is definitely accessible as evidenced by is_readable();